# How to implement a $j$-level $M$-band wavelet transform of an image?

Tags: image-processing, wavelet, multi-channel

I want to implement an $M$-band (or multi-band) wavelet transform, to be used for feature extraction on images.

- Is there a built-in Matlab function available?
- Do I have to implement is using filter coefficients?
- Where can I get filter coefficients for $M$-band wavelets?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  What have you tried? Can't you find anything [from Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=k-+level+M-Band+wavelet+transform+of+an+image%3F&oq=k-+level+M-Band+wavelet+transform+of+an+image%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=k-+level+M-Band+wavelet+transform+of+an+image%3F+matlab)? Why do you need to do it? Is it just matlab? Or will C code do?

Comment: @Peter K. while the question deserves some editing, I understand it. There are few available $M$-band wavelet filter directly available. I have an implement of a $M$-band that I did not make public yet. I should clean the code and do something with that.

Comment: OK, @LaurentDuval: I don't mean to discourage useratstat, but it does seem like a better asked question could be made of it.  Perhaps you could try editing?

Comment: Was this question successfully answered?

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT: some code made available]  The  notion of $M$-band wavelet transform, $M\ge2$, generalizes the standard $2$-band wavelet. The theory is provides, for instance, in [Theory Of Regular M-Band Wavelet Bases](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/78.258088), P. Steffen *et al.*, 1993. Remember that with $2$-band wavelets, one cannot obtain wavelets that are real-valued, symmetric, orthogonal and with finite support, except for the Haar wavelet (not very regular). For $M>2$, such designs can be obtained with sufficient regularity, and $M$-band wavelets are sometimes believed to be more efficient for image analysis.

[image]

Alas, regular $M$-band filterbank are generally harder to design, and $M$-band wavelets have been used more rarely. Resultingly, they are less implemented in standard software.

On $M$-band implementations: I am not aware of build-in Matlab functions. However, there exist $1$D versions, that you can built upon for your applications:

- LTFAT (Large Time-Frequency Analysis Toolbox) : [WFILT_CMBAND](http://ltfat.sourceforge.net/doc/wavelets/wfilt_cmband.php) - Generates $$M$-Band cosine modulated wavelet filters, from [On cosine-modulated wavelet orthonormal bases](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/83.342190), 1995
- [M-band dual-tree wavelet](http://www-syscom.univ-mlv.fr/~chaux/toolbox/TOOLBOX_DTMband1D_v1.2.zip): Shannon & Meyer wavelets, and Modulated Lapped Transforms for specific $M$s, and a $4$-band filter from [Design of Efficient $M$-Band Coders with Linear-Phase and Perfect-Reconstruction Properties](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/78.398719), 1995, Alkin and Caglar. They  come with their Hiilbert transform, and are detailed in [Image Analysis Using a Dual-Tree M-Band Wavelet Transform](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2006.875178), 2006; [Noise Covariance Properties in Dual-Tree Wavelet Decompositions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2007.909104), 2007; [A Nonlinear Stein Based Estimator for Multichannel Image Denoising](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2008.921757), 2008. Below, 2D oriented $4$-band wavelets from Alkin and Caglar:

[image: Dual wavelets from Alkin & Caglar]

A $2$-D version is now embedded in the Matlab toolbox:  [$M$-band $2$D dual-tree (Hilbert) wavelet multicomponent image denoising.](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56705-m-band-2d-dual-tree--hilbert--wavelet-multicomponent-image-denoising) Other sources to grab coefficients from:

-[An algebraic construction of orthonormal $M$-band wavelets with perfect reconstruction](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2004.11.025)

And one day, I shall rewrite my own codes to make them much cleaner.