# Code for a wavelet based hilbert transform?

Tags: wavelet, phase, software-implementation, hilbert-transform

I normally implement the Hilbert transform using the Fourier transform.

I have noise related issues I want to solve. Does anybody have an (apodized) implementation of the Hilbert transform handy, preferably using a wavelet transform or some other kind of band limited convolution?

Any hints on how to generate a 1D or 2D kernel for instantaneous phase extract would be appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for a code written to specification, are generally considered as off-topic.

Comment: @Mikhail Did you find want you were looking for, despite the closing?

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug ahead.

A 1D $M$-band dual-tree wavelet toolbox can be found in [1D Wavelet decompositions : Matlab toolbox for 1D dual-tree M-band wavelet decomposition](https://www.projet-plume.org/en/relier/1d-wavelet-decompositions), and we just shared the 2D version embedded in a code for multivariate Gaussian noise image filtering in [$M$-band 2D dual-tree (Hilbert) wavelet multicomponent image denoising](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56705-m-band-2d-dual-tree--hilbert--wavelet-multicomponent-image-denoising). It is not  as clean as I wished, I hope I can work on a specific version soon.

Actually, although the primal wavelet fiters are FIR, these wavelets are implemented in the Fourier domain, as for splines. We found that pure time- or space- FIR approximations for their implemetation included directional issues. We choosed  $M$-band wavelets because they allow orthogonality, symmmetry and finite support. We suspect that the finer frequency decomposition is beneficial to the Hilbert transform, that works better on band-limited signals.

Another discussion can be found in [What are the most popular wavelet or tight frame regularizers for image reconstruction problems?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/what-are-the-most-popular-wavelet-or-tight-frame-regularizers-for-image-reconstr/23601#23601) and in [How to implement a $j$-level $M$-band wavelet transform of an image?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29634/how-to-implement-a-j-level-m-band-wavelet-transform-of-an-image/29638#29638)

For the sake of diversity, you can find other ($2$-band) codes [here](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/siva-signal-image-links.html#siva-dual-tree-wavelets).